# How can i position several elements with icons beside each other in one div?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I want to create a call to action section in the header of my site, i want a picture on one side, and on the other side i want to put a title (h1 specifically) and a paragraph and finally a button to direct the user to another div on the page. My problem is in positioning elements all beside each other. I tried putting each of the elements in a separate div, but didn’t work. I used clear:both, still not aligned as i want. So i decided to ask here and learn the right way to doing it. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different things you can do. Most simply you can set the individual elements to a display of "inline-block". This doesn't give you as much control though as other things like display "flex" or "grid" which you can set on the parent elements. 
I'd recommend this documentation to get started with CSS grid, which is the more modern way of accomplishing this: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout